# Booting Linux breaks Windows Aero in dual-boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I got a weird problem here: I have a notebook with a 9700M GT card, and Windows 7 final/Ubuntu 9.10 in Dual-Boot.

Booting Ubuntu works fine, graphics output is good, I got compositing -- using the nVidia binary driver. But if I boot (i.e. "warm reboot") into Win7 right after Ubuntu, the card reports Error 43 in the hardware manager, and Aero gets disabled. Rebooting and starting Win7 again, everything works (i.e. Aero is working fine, glass everywhere, etc.). Shutting the machine down in Ubuntu and starting Windows 7 also works fine, it's just in the "soft reboot" scenario that I have problems.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Is this after a soft reboot? Can you replicate by shutting down the computer after Ubuntu, and then going into Windows 7 from cold start?

Comment: I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Yeah, only after a soft reboot. After power-cycling, Aero works correctly right away.

Comment: I mean, this does probably not help you, but...there were similar issues with WLAN-Chipsets which couldn't be recognized if it was a coldboot into Linux, the users needed to boot to windows and then softboot to Linux for the chipsets to be recognized correctly. This was an issue with initializing the chip or something. Maybe there's a bug in the new NVidia-Driver which prevents the card from being freed correctly or something similar. I'd try my luck in the nvidia-boards or support with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had Windows machines which couldn't soft reboot, even without dual boot, meaning from Windows into Windows. You might try this out on your machine.

I've been searching for an explanation or solution for years, without success, until I changed machines. Everyone I mentioned this to was extremely surprised and had no ideas to contribute, both software and hardware specialists. I finally gave up and just did hard boots.

Comment: soft rebooting Windows works, and also soft-rebooting from Ubuntu 9.04 to Win7 worked. It's just since I installed 9.10 that a soft-reboot would break Aero

Comment: Following on from harrymc and Bobby, I'd just do a hard reboot. It might be that Ubuntu's new drivers are causing it. Who knows? It's not that much of a problem as workarounds go.